# Filtering by JOIN, UNION, INTERSECT, EXCEPT

Tags: sql, join, union

I have these two tables:

```
CREATE TABLE set (
  id INT PRIMARY KEY;
  value TEXT NOT NULL
);

CREATE TABLE filter (
  id INT PRIMARY KEY
);
```

The set TABLE contains some information tied to an id. A very large set in the reality.
The filter TABLE should act like a filter as explained below. If any, it will contain a subset of the id values found in the set TABLE.

What I need to do in a single query is:

1. If the filter is empty, I need to get all elements in the set (negative filter).
2. If the filter is not empty, I need to get the INNER JOIN, thus a proper filtering.

I would prefer not to discriminate on COUNT(*) on the filter but rather exploit JOINs, UNIONs, INTERSECTs and EXCEPTs.

How would you write such a query?

Comment: How come you prefer some constructions before others? Can you give some sample data and wanted result?

Comment: have you tried using a LEFT OUTER JOIN?

Comment: The question is about a single query. This is why I need to avoid the IF.

Comment: Which DBMS are you using? Postgres?

Comment: @VB1, That would not work unless you make a IF-equivalent with the COUNT(*) on the filter. As the filter is a subset of the set, the LOJ would result in the set itself.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name I am using PostgreSQL. But it should work with all SQL RDBMS.

Comment: Not all DBMS support `intersect` or `except` (and in Oracle `except` is called `minus`). Plus: writing DBMS independent statements essenstially means that the statement runs equally slow on all DBMS (if you can find such a statement in the first place)

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name I need this under PostgreSQL but also need to communicate with people running other RDBMS. Usually "real" ones do a good job with reasonable design. But not all of them. This is why I put that constraint...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's one approach using an `outer join` with `not exists`:

```
select s.id, s.value
from set s
    left join filter on s.id = filter.id 
where not exists (select 1 from filter) or s.id = filter.id
```

It's a little counter intuitive -- but basically, if no records exist in the filter table, return all. Else, return only those that match...

Comment: This thing actually works. It's a left join, though. The "WHERE NOT EXISTS... OR" is the IF-equivalent I was willing to avoid. I was hoping to avoid it...

Comment: @enzo: a left join **is** an outer join

Comment: You're not going to do any better than this answer really for what you're looking for